# replacing selector 'ul:first-child' with class '.list_wrapper:first-child'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selector

I have a box with text within that scrolling up like the old known marquee tag.

I am using the jquery scrollbox that I found on this website:

http://wmh.github.io/jquery-scrollbox/

now, in my css file I want to replace the ul & il tags with classes, say: .list_wrapper would be instead of ul, and .list would be instead of li, so far so good...

after modifying the css, the scroller stopped to work, i found that i need to modify the "jquery.scrollbox.js" file too, but my knowledge in js is basic.

my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.scrollbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#marquee {
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
#marquee .list_wrapper {
    width: 165px;
    line-height: 25px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#marquee .list {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('#marquee').scrollbox({
    linear: true,
    step: 1,
    delay: 0,
    speed: 65
  });  
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="marquee">
  <div class="list_wrapper">
    <div class="list">• text 1</div>
    <div class="list">• text 2</div>
    <div class="list">• text 3</div>
    <div class="list">• text 4</div>
    <div class="list">• text 5</div>
    <div class="list">• text 6</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

heres ths js file (I think there's something to do with the "('ul:first-child') and ('li:first-child'):

```
/*!
 * jQuery Scrollbox
 * (c) 2009-2013 Hunter Wu <hunter.wu@gmail.com>
 * MIT Licensed.
 *
 * http://github.com/wmh/jquery-scrollbox
 */

(function($) {

$.fn.scrollbox = function(config) {
  //default config
  var defConfig = {
    linear: false,          // Scroll method
    startDelay: 2,          // Start delay (in seconds)
    delay: 3,               // Delay after each scroll event (in seconds)
    step: 5,                // Distance of each single step (in pixels)
    speed: 32,              // Delay after each single step (in milliseconds)
    switchItems: 1,         // Items to switch after each scroll event
    direction: 'vertical',
    distance: 'auto',
    autoPlay: true,
    onMouseOverPause: true,
    paused: false,
    queue: null
  };
  config = $.extend(defConfig, config);
  config.scrollOffset = config.direction === 'vertical' ? 'scrollTop' : 'scrollLeft';
  if (config.queue) {
    config.queue = $('#' + config.queue);
  }

  return this.each(function() {
    var container = $(this),
        containerUL,
        scrollingId = null,
        nextScrollId = null,
        paused = false,
        backward,
        forward,
        resetClock,
        scrollForward,
        scrollBackward;

    if (config.onMouseOverPause) {
      container.bind('mouseover', function() { paused = true; });
      container.bind('mouseout', function() { paused = false; });
    }
    containerUL = container.children('ul:first-child');

    scrollForward = function() {
      if (paused) {
        return;
      }
      var curLi,
          i,
          newScrollOffset,
          scrollDistance,
          theStep;

      curLi = containerUL.children('li:first-child');

      scrollDistance = config.distance !== 'auto' ? config.distance :
        config.direction === 'vertical' ? curLi.height() : curLi.width();

      // offset
      if (!config.linear) {
        theStep = Math.max(3, parseInt((scrollDistance - container[0][config.scrollOffset]) * 0.3, 10));
        newScrollOffset = Math.min(container[0][config.scrollOffset] + theStep, scrollDistance);
      } else {
        newScrollOffset = Math.min(container[0][config.scrollOffset] + config.step, scrollDistance);
      }
      container[0][config.scrollOffset] = newScrollOffset;

      if (newScrollOffset >= scrollDistance) {
        for (i = 0; i < config.switchItems; i++) {
          if (config.queue && config.queue.hasChildNodes() && config.queue.getElementsByTagName('li').length > 0) {
            containerUL.append(config.queue.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
            containerUL.remove(containerUL.children('li:first-child'));
          } else {
            containerUL.append(containerUL.children('li:first-child'));
          }
        }
        container[0][config.scrollOffset] = 0;
        clearInterval(scrollingId);
        if (config.autoPlay) {
          nextScrollId = setTimeout(forward, config.delay * 1000);
        }
      }
    };

    // Backward
    // 1. If forwarding, then reverse
    // 2. If stoping, then backward once
    scrollBackward = function() {
      if (paused) {
        return;
      }
      var curLi,
          i,
          liLen,
          newScrollOffset,
          scrollDistance,
          theStep;

      // init
      if (container[0][config.scrollOffset] === 0) {
        liLen = containerUL.children('li').length;
        for (i = 0; i < config.switchItems; i++) {
          containerUL.children('li:last-child').insertBefore(containerUL.children('li:first-child'));
        }

        curLi = container.children('li:first-child');
        scrollDistance = config.distance !== 'auto' ?
            config.distance :
            config.direction === 'vertical' ? curLi.height() : curLi.width();
        container[0][config.scrollOffset] = scrollDistance;
      }

      // new offset
      if (!config.linear) {
        theStep = Math.max(3, parseInt(container[0][config.scrollOffset] * 0.3, 10));
        newScrollOffset = Math.max(container[0][config.scrollOffset] - theStep, 0);
      } else {
        newScrollOffset = Math.max(container[0][config.scrollOffset] - config.step, 0);
      }
      container[0][config.scrollOffset] = newScrollOffset;

      if (newScrollOffset === 0) {
        clearInterval(scrollingId);
        if (config.autoPlay) {
          nextScrollId = setTimeout(forward, config.delay * 1000);
        }
      }
    };

    forward = function() {
      clearInterval(scrollingId);
      scrollingId = setInterval(scrollForward, config.speed);
    };

    backward = function() {
      clearInterval(scrollingId);
      scrollingId = setInterval(scrollBackward, config.speed);
    };

    resetClock = function(delay) {
      config.delay = delay || config.delay;
      clearTimeout(nextScrollId);
      if (config.autoPlay) {
        nextScrollId = setTimeout(forward, config.delay * 1000);
      }
    };

    if (config.autoPlay) {
      nextScrollId = setTimeout(forward, config.startDelay * 1000);
    }

    // bind events for container
    container.bind('resetClock', function(delay) { resetClock(delay); });
    container.bind('forward', function() { clearTimeout(nextScrollId); forward(); });
    container.bind('backward', function() { clearTimeout(nextScrollId); backward(); });
    container.bind('speedUp', function(speed) {
      if (typeof speed === 'undefined') {
        speed = Math.max(1, parseInt(config.speed / 2, 10));
      }
      config.speed = speed;
    });
    container.bind('speedDown', function(speed) {
      if (typeof speed === 'undefined') {
        speed = config.speed * 2;
      }
      config.speed = speed;
    });
  });
};

}(jQuery));
```

thank you!

Comment: try change  `('ul:first-child')` to `('.list_wrapper:first-child')` and `('li:first-child')` to `('.list:first-child')`

Comment: You should not change `ul` and `li` to `div` (no way, if it is a list - your HTML should be semantical). You can simply add the CSS classes if you need to, and maybe reset default styling browsers apply to lists. That's the way to go.

Comment: @TusharGupta, thank you for your responding, I tried to do what you 
suggest and it's working, well almost... the text scroling only one time and stops, it should be repeated -but we almost there!

Comment: try `('li:first-child')` to `('.list_wrapper li:first-child')`

Comment: @bažmegakapa, thank you, but I need it in divs, it's more flexible for me, and a few more reasons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open jquery-scrollbox.js and try to change by the hand (not automatically) all ul&li tag on div tag

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the answer. Author write "i found that i need to modify the "jquery.scrollbox.js" file too, but my knowledge in js is basic." (c).

Comment: Perhaps the author picked up the wrong title to the question, but my answer solve his problem, I checked it :)

Comment: @MaryTarasenko, thank you very much, it's working! The thing is that I tried your suggest, before I come here, and it didn't worked, maybe I missed something.. Anyway thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/4af3Y/